# R-squared for observed and modeled relative to 1:1 line in R

Tags: r

This question may sound a little bit weird. I want to know how can I report the R-sqaured value in R compared to 1:1 line. For example I want to compare the observed and modeled values. In the ideal case, it should be a straight line passing through an origin at an angle of 45 degrees.

For example I have a data which can be found on https://www.dropbox.com/s/71u2vsgt7p9k5cl/correlationcsv

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
> corsen<- read.table("Sensitivity Runs/correlationcsv",sep=",",header=T)
> linsensitivity <- lm(data=corsen,sensitivity~0+observed)
> summary(linsensitivity)

Call:
lm(formula = sensitivity ~ 0 + observed, data = corsen)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.37615 -0.03376  0.00515  0.04155  0.27213 

Coefficients:
         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
observed 0.833660   0.001849   450.8   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.05882 on 2988 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.9855, Adjusted R-squared: 0.9855 
F-statistic: 2.032e+05 on 1 and 2988 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

The plot looks like following:

```
ggplot(corsen,aes(observed,sensitivity))+geom_point()+geom_smooth(method="lm",aes(color="red"))+
  ylab(" Modeled (m)")+xlab("Observed (m)")+
  geom_line(data=oneline,aes(x=onelinex,y=oneliney,color="blue"))+ 
  scale_color_manual("",values=c("red","blue"),label=c("1:1 line","Regression Line"))+theme_bw()+theme(legend.position="top")+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-0.2,2),ylim=c(-0.2,2))
```

[image: Correlation plot]

My question is that if we look closely the data are off from the 1:1 line. How can I find the R-squared relative to the 1:1 line ? Right now the linear model I used is regardless of the line specified. It is purely based on the data provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the residuals and sum their squares:

```
 resid2 <- with( corsen, sum( sensitivity-observed)^2 ))
```

If you wanted an R^2 like number I suppose you could calculate:

```
 R2like <- 1 - resid2/ with(corsen, sum( sensitivity^2))
```